# How to set variables via style tag in Next.js during SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I set scss variables during SSR? The following code is not working.
The props from config are ok btw, I can set the colors on client but not with the style tag in SSR.

_app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps, config }) => {
...
// config.primary = string that represents a color hex
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <style jsx global>{`
          :root {
            --primary: ${config.primary};
          }
        `}</style>
      </Head>
      <h1>Hello Next.js!</h1>
      <p>This is an example of setting SCSS variables via a style tag in Next.js.</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```